# Run PDO mysql connect without opening the browser

Tags: php, batch-file, pdo, mysql-connector

I have a PDO script where I write data to mysql, it works fine with localhost. However, when I want to run it at certain intervals with the .bat file, I cannot connect to Mysql. What method should I use? Details are below. Thanks.

Mamp Server on Windows
WebServer Nginx

PDO MySQL Connect

```
try {
    $bag = new PDO("mysql:host=$ip;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
    $bag->exec("SET CHARSET UTF8");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die("Mistake! Please, contact to admin...");
}
```

.BAT file

`"C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.0.0\php.exe" -f C:\MAMP\htdocs\writetomysql.php`

Error is: could not find driver.

Comment: Call the webserver with `http://localhost/writetomysql.php`

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, it gives an error. Error is :  could not open input file :  http://localhost:443/writetomysql.php

Comment: 443 is ssl, are you sure that you have ssl enabled in the ngix config, with a valid key, try it without port

Comment: It gives the same error when I make the port default. :(  without port

Comment: could it be, that another driver is meant?

Comment: It's impossible because it's just insert into MySQL with PDO, there is nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for ngink it doesn't work with php.exe try to use php-cgi.exe

Also You need to have a module called pdo_mysql. Looking in phpinfo(),

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version => *****

Comment: Unfortunately, php-cgi.exe also gives the same error. Could it be because of the version?

PDO Driver for MySQL
Client API version : mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

Comment: Do you have only Mysqlnd, but you have no  PDO_Mysql right?

Comment: I have. phpinfo()
pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL enabled
Client API version mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id:.....